# How to split a column into multiple columns by condition delimeter in SQL?

Tags: sql, split, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

could anyone help me please?

I have this column

**Column**`<br/>`

John > Doe Doe > Writer`<br/>`

Jane > Doe > Chemical Engineer > Sovena`<br/>`

**I want to my final result to be**

**Column**`<br/>`

John`<br/>`

Jane`<br/>`

**Column2**`<br/>`

Doe Doe`<br/>`

Doe`<br/>`

**Column3**`<br/>`

Writer`<br/>`

Chemical Engineer`<br/>`

**Column4**`<br/>`

(Empty) `<br/>`

Sovena`<br/>`

**I need this in SQL, split by ">" could you help?
Thanks!**

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific functionality will probably be used.)

Comment: Display the expected result in proper columns, to make it easier to read.

Comment: If, when, and wherever possible, avoid storing data in relational databases like this. It is quick and easy to build and implement, and extraordinarily hard to work with thereafter. Always speak up against such designs!.

Comment: This is an extraction, this code is for storing the data in a easy way to work in future. I use Python but in this case it was asked to help using SQL. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

Unfortunately, the string splitting functionality that is built-in does not provide an index for the components.  So, one solution is a recursive subquery:

```
with cte as (
      select id, convert(varchar(max), NULL) as str,
             convert(varchar(max), str) as rest, 0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select id, left(rest, charindex(' > ', rest + ' > ') - 1),
             stuff(rest, 1, charindex(' > ', rest + ' > ') + 2, ''),
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest <> '' 
     )
select max(case when lev = 1 then str end),
       max(case when lev = 2 then str end),
       max(case when lev = 3 then str end),
       max(case when lev = 4 then str end)
from cte
group by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=342b5a12eb64ac387d633276e06b8b0b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the help! I'm new at ask questions here so sorry for the few information at the beginning. Could you help again please? I've edited the problem

Comment: @JoãoAzevedo . . . You should revert this question and ask a new question.  By changing the question, you invalidate this answer, which can cause downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried to make a new question but i don't have permission